# I want to add active class to menu and submenu by using PHP. I have added it ib submenu but on main menu I am having problems

Tags: php

```
<li class="nav-item  <?php if($page=='userforms'){echo 'active';}?>

    <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle" style="">
        <i class="icon-layers"></i>
        <span class="title">Userforms</span>
        <span class="arrow open"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li class="nav-item <?php if($page=='newproduct'){echo 'active';}?>">
            <a href="add.php" class="nav-link ">
                <span class="title">New Product</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item  <?php if($page=='stockin'){echo 'active';}?>">
            <a href="StockIn.php" class="nav-link ">
                <span class="title">Stock In</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item  <?php if($page=='stockout'){echo 'active';}?>">
            <a href="StockOut.php" class="nav-link ">
                <span class="title">Stock Out</span>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</li>


<?php $page = 'stockin'; include('includes/header.php'); 
include('includes/navbar.php'); 
?>
```

I want to add active class to menu and submenu by using PHP. I have added it ib submenu but on main menu I am having problems. I want both menu to be selected Main menu and Sub Menu.

[I want both menu to be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7CdD.png)

Comment: there's a typo missing closing double quotes on the class `<li class="nav-item  <?php if($page=='userforms'){echo 'active';}?>`

Comment: Hello, I have posted you answer. if it is helpful pls mark it as correct.

Comment: lachiweb solved my problem thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<li class="nav-item  <?php if($page=='userforms'){echo 'active';}?>
```

With

```
<li class="nav-item <?php if ($page == 'userforms' || $page == 'stockin' || $page == 'newproduct' || $page == 'stockout') echo 'active'; ?>">
```

Then, both menu link will be active and also you had a typo mistake in `<li>` tag

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible only by CSS. You should use some javascript codes.

```
$('.child').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('.parent').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: _“It's not possible only by CSS”_ - that’s why they are dynamically adding the `active`  class, when creating the page. _“You should use some javascript codes”_ - that would only work on the current page, as soon as the next page loads (_because_ a navigation link was clicked), this change would be gone again.

Comment: I am trying to do it with PHP not CSS